# Ошибки при переустановке phpmyadmin

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, dpkg

При попытке снести phpmyadmin, выдает такие ошибки:

> ERROR: Config file rpaf.conf not
>   properly enabled:
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.conf is
>   a real file, not touching it dpkg:
>   error processing package apache2
>   (--configure): subprocess installed
>   post-installation script returned
>   error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of
>   apache2-mpm-prefork:
>   apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2
>   (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1); however: Package
>   apache2 is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package
>   apache2-mpm-prefork (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
>   prevent configuration of
>   libapache2-mod-php5:
>   libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2
>   (>= 2.4); however: Package apache2 is
>   not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package
>   libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving
>   unconfigured No apport report written
>   because the error message indicates
>   its a followup error from a previous
>   failure. No apport report written
>   because the error message indicates
>   its a followup error from a previous
>   failure. Errors were encountered while
>   processing: apache2
>   apache2-mpm-prefork
>   libapache2-mod-php5 E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
>   (1)

Как это исправить?

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure apache2?

Comment: на эту команду выдало "/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: apache2 is broken or not fully installed"

пробувал перезапустить apache - выдало
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                       no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

в логах нету ничего((

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: Config file rpaf.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.conf is a real file, not touching it

в каталоге `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` должны лежать не файлы, а «мягкие» ссылки (symlinks) на файлы в каталоге `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`.

для данного случая я бы порекомендовал переместить куда-нибудь этот файл (`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.conf`), а затем повторить конфигурацию пакетов, которые не доконфигурировались:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

файл потом (при необходимости) можно, конечно, вернуть, но лучше всё-таки задействовать тот, что лежит в `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rpaf
```